# Separate Dead letter queue for each topic in kafka connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm implementing streaming using kafka connect in one of my projects. I have created S3 sink connector to consume messages from different topics (using regex) and then write a file to S3. Consuming messages from different topics is done using the below property.

`"topics.regex": "my-topic-sample\\.(.+)",`

I have 3 different topics as below. Using the above property, S3 sink connector will consume messages from these 3 topics and writes a separate file (for each topic) to S3.

```
my-topic-sample.test1
my-topic-sample.test2
my-topic-sample.test3
```

For now, ignoring all the invalid messages. However, want to implement dead letter queue.

We can achieve that using the below properties

```
'errors.tolerance'='all',
'errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name' = 'error_topic'
```

From the above property, we can move all the invalid messages to DLQ. But the issue is that we will have only 1 DLQ though there are 3 different topics from which S3 sink connector is consuming the messages. Invalid messages from all the 3 topics will be pushed to same DLQ.

Is there a way that we can have multiple DLQ's and write the message to a different DLQ based on the topic that was consumed from.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can only configure a single DLQ topic per connector, it's not possible to use a different DLQ topic for each source topic.

Today if you want to split records your connector fails to process into different DLQ topics, you need to start multiple connector instances each consuming from a different source topic.

---

Apache Kafka is an open source project so if you are up for the challenge, you can propose implementing such a feature if you want to. See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Improvement+Proposals for the overall process.